# How to access/change permission(like INTERNET) of other apps from an android app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to make an app which can change permission of other apps.
for example- suppose CAMERA app need Camera access I want an app which can change the permissions of CAMERA APP by Allowing/Denying the use of Camera.
How can I do so ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without providing a custom ROM.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible in general, for obvious security reasons. There are probably hacks for doing this on rooted devices, and there *might* be options in the device owner APIs.